# Setting diff versions in github code review

Tags: github

A colleague committed (C1) a bunch of new code to github, and I made some line comments through the github ui and asked her to respond to those before I completed the review.  She did, submitting a new commit (C2).  When I go to review her new code, I am shown the differences between C1 and C2, which is not what I want.  For example, I'm very interested in code that appears in both C1 and C2.  Also, I'm not interested in the changes she made from C1 to C2 that are not directly related to my comments; they're just a visual distraction.  Is there a way to view commit C2 and make line comments on it without viewing it as a diff from C1?

EDIT: See the clarifying comment in response to @NullToken's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted GitHub support and was given this partial URL to generate diffs between two arbitrary commits:

```
repo/compare/SHA…SHA
```

They confirmed that they do not support line notes in this view but said they would add it to the feature request list.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to view commit C2 and make line comments on it without viewing it as a diff from C1?

- Click on the C2 commit link

[image: commit link]

- This will open the commit by itself and only show the code that has been changed as part of this commit
- Add line notes

[image: notes marker]

- Those comments will also appear on the Pull Request

**UPDATE following comment**

> I'd like to be able to see the current code without any diff annotations but still be able to comment on it

Currently, there's no way to add comments to the plain source code. The Pull Request is at the center of the collaborative workflow promoted by GitHub. And I don't know of any hack to turn off the Diff display.

How about [contacting the GitHub support](https://github.com/contact) with your feature request?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the pictures, but my goal is to not also see the diffs from the previous commitment (shown in yellow and red in your picture).  I'd like to be able to see the current code without any diff annotations but still be able to comment on it.

Comment: thanks for additional response.  I'll make a feature request.